# parsing google news using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have python code as below. It searches a google news page and prints hyperlinks and titles for each news. My problem is that googlenews groups news that are similar in one bucket and below script prints only 1st news in each bucket. How can I print all new from all buckets?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

#r = requests.get('http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts', headers=headers)
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eric+bledsoe%22&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:d', headers=headers)
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lebron+james%22&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:y', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

letters = soup.find_all("div", class_="_cnc")
#print soup.prettify() 
#print letters
print type(letters)
print len(letters)
print("\n")

for x in range(0, len(letters)):
    print x
    print letters[x].a["href"]


print("\n")

letters2 = soup.find_all("a", class_="l _HId")
for x in range(0, len(letters2)):
    print x
    print letters2[x].get_text()

print ("\n----------content")
#print letters[0]
```

By bucketing news I mean that in the below image, first few news are grouped together. The news "LeBron James compares one of his teammates to Denn" is part of another group.

[image]

Comment: You might find yourself getting blocked by google

Comment: did you downgrade my question? is that why you downgraded my question (if you have)? i already ran this query and so far google hasnt blocked me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a whole new shift to kill I decided to take a more efficient stab at the problem, this way you just have to append queries to search for new players.  I'm not sure what you want for an end result but this will return a list of dictionaries.

```
import bs4
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}


#just add to this list for each new player
#player name : url
queries = {"bledsoe":"https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eric+bledsoe%22&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:d",
           "james":"https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lebron+james%22&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:y"}


total = []

for player in queries: #keys

    #request the google query url of each player
    req  = requests.get(queries[player], headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

    #look for the main container
    for each in soup.find_all("div"):
        results = {player: { \
            "link": None,    \
            "title": None,   \
            "source": None,  \
            "time": None}    \
        }

        try:
          #if <div> doesn't have class="anything"
          #it will throw a keyerror, just ignore

          if "_cnc" in each.attrs["class"]: #mainstories
            results[player]["link"] = each.find("a")["href"]
            results[player]["title"] = each.find("a").get_text()
            sourceAndTime = each.contents[1].get_text().split("-")
            results[player]["source"], results[player]["time"] = sourceAndTime
            total.append(results)

          elif "card-section" in each.attrs["class"]: #buckets
            results[player]["link"] = each.find("a")["href"]
            results[player]["title"] = each.find("a").get_text()
            results[player]["source"] = each.contents[1].contents[0].get_text()
            results[player]["time"] = each.contents[1].get_text()
            total.append(results)

        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add line numbers where each text was found? That way we can deferentiate between main stories and sub stories. Appreciate your efforts

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the code after the `try` statement. I commented which is which, the `class = "_cnc"` wold be a mainstory and the sub would be `class = " card-section"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by bucket?  If you mean you're trying to parse multiple websites then I can tell you you're overwriting `r` by sending it multiple news `requests.get()`

Here's a loop to process all the URLs you have in the urls array.

```
import bs4
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}


urls = ["https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eric+bledsoe%22&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:d",
        "https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lebron+james%22&tbm=nws&tbs=qdr:y"]

ahrefs = []
titles = []

for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

    #you don't even have to process the div container
    #just go strait to <a> and using indexing get "href"
    #headlines
    ahref  = [a["href"] for a in soup.find_all("a", class_="_HId")]
    #"buckets"
    ahref += [a["href"] for a in soup.find_all("a", class_="_sQb")]
    ahrefs.append(ahref)

    #or get_text() will return the array inside the hyperlink
    #the title you want
    title =  [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("a", class_="_HId")]
    title += [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("a", class_="_sQb")]
    titles.append(title)

#print(ahrefs)
#print(titles)
```

My google search for lebron turns up 18 results, including subheadlines, and `len(ahrefs[1]) == 18`

Comment: I tried your code. But with lebron james query, there are more than 20 news on the first page. But your query returns less than 15 :(

Comment: for example the news `LeBron James still can't believe teams are leaving him this wide open
FOXSports.com-2 hours ago` doesnt appear at all in your query's results

Comment: i also modified my question to explain buckets

Comment: That's because the "bucket" news sources have a different class than the headlines `<a class = "_sQb">`

Comment: would it be also possible to show how to add time stamp, source and description text that comes with each news?

Comment: I tried `xyz =  [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("span", class_="f nsa _uQb")]` but that gave me only few dates :( Moreover number of news given by xyz are not equal to number of groups/block on the google news page :(

Comment: fyi: i would like to maintain sequence when i get source information. I tried `source =  [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("span", class_="_tQb _IId")]` and 'source += [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("span", class_="_Wmc _GId")]' But the number of entries that i get for href and titles are different and I also get a different sequence :(

Comment: Well by appending "_Wmc" your adding extra length to the array that not every news source has.  Ill update the source in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for this container that has all the needed data:

```py
for result in soup.select('.WlydOe'):
    title = result.select_one('.nDgy9d').text
    link = result['href']
```

To get more accurate results that you see in your browser, you can pass additional query parameters as a `dict()` to request, just like with adding `headers`:

```py
params = {
    "q": "best potato recipes",   # query
    "hl": "en",                   # language (English)
    "gl": "us",                   # country to search from (United States)
    "tbm": "nws",                 # news results filter
    "tbs": "qdr:d"
}
requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-Python-BS4-Request#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "will minecraft become the best game on the planet?",
    "hl": "en",
    "gl": "us",
    "tbm": "nws",
    "tbs": "qdr:d"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.WlydOe'):
    title = result.select_one('.nDgy9d').text
    link = result['href']
    print(title, link, sep='\n')

---------
'''
Best Lemon Roasted Potatoes Recipe - How to Make Lemon Roasted Potatoes
https://parade.com/1256318/kristamarshall/lemon-roasted-potatoes/
Best Potatoes for Potato Salad
https://greatist.com/eat/best-type-potato-for-potato-salad
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google News Results API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want fast, instead of looking and figuring out how to extract the data, pick the correct selector, understand why certain things don't work as expected, and then to maintain it over time.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "best potato recipe",
  "tbm": "nws",
  "tbs": "qdr:d",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for news_result in results["news_results"]:
  print(f"Title: {news_result['title']}\nLink: {news_result['link']}\n")

---------
'''
Best Lemon Roasted Potatoes Recipe - How to Make Lemon Roasted Potatoes
https://parade.com/1256318/kristamarshall/lemon-roasted-potatoes/

Best Potatoes for Potato Salad
https://greatist.com/eat/best-type-potato-for-potato-salad
...
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more in-depth blog post about how to scrape [Google News Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-news-with-python-4o14).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.